# Protractor+Typescript => Getting "Failed: Cannot read property 'sendKeys' of undefined"

Tags: selenium, typescript, protractor, automated-tests

I am trying create protractor js spec files using type script and facing below error while running the converted spec files.

Failed: clculator_1.calculator.prototype.getResult is not a function

Below are the type script files.

### calculator.ts

```
import { element, browser, by, ExpectedConditions as EC, ElementFinder, ElementArrayFinder } from 'protractor';



export class calculator {

    firstElement = element(by.model('first'));
    secondElement = element(by.model('second'));
    submit = element(by.id('gobutton'));
    operator = element.all(by.options('value for (key, value) in operators'));





     getResult=(val1: string, val2: string, operator: string):any=>{

        this.firstElement.sendKeys(val1);
        this.secondElement.sendKeys(val2);
        // this.operator.$$("option:contains('" + operator + "')").click();

    }



}
```

### SampleSpec.ts

```
 import { browser, by, until, ExpectedConditions as EC, Key, element, ElementFinder } from "protractor";

import { helperUtility as util } from '../utility/helperUtility';

import { calculator as calc } from '../pages/clculator';

beforeEach(() => {
    util.prototype.isAngular(false);
    browser.get('https://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
});


describe('Test login functionality', () => {

    xit('should login the user and allow to logout ', () => {

        var resultCountBefore = element(by.repeater('result in memory'));
        element(by.model('first')).sendKeys('3');
        element(by.model('second')).sendKeys('5');
        element(by.id('gobutton')).click();


        browser.wait(EC.or(isResultUpdated), 5000);
        browser.sleep(500);
        let result = element(by.xpath("//button[@id='gobutton']/../h2")).getText();
        expect(result).toEqual('8');


    });


    it('test mathemetical operation', () => {


        browser.waitForAngular();
        calc.prototype.getResult('1','2','+');



    });


});





export let isResultUpdated = function () {

    return element(by.xpath("//button[@id='gobutton']/../h2")).getText().then(function (result) {
        console.info(result + ' is the result')
        return result == '. . . . . .';
    });


};
```

### config.ts

```
import { ProtractorBrowser, Config,browser } from 'protractor';

export let config: Config = {

    allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
    baseUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    capabilities:{
        browserName:'chrome'
    },
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },
    onPrepare: () => {
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);

    },specs:['../specs/First.spec.js'],

};
```

Error

```
Failures:
1) Test login functionality test mathemetical operation
  Message:
    Failed: clculator_1.calculator.prototype.getResult is not a function
  Stack:
    TypeError: clculator_1.calculator.prototype.getResult is not a function
        at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Selenium2\Protractor\TypeScriptProject\ConvertedJSFiles\specs\First.spec.js:22:42)
        at C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:102:25
        at new ManagedPromise (C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\
promise.js:1067:7)
        at controlFlowExecute (C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:87:
18)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\
promise.js:2970:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\
lib\promise.js:2953:27)
        at asyncRun (C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js
:2860:25)
        at C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:676:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    From: Task: Run it("test mathemetical operation") in control flow
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:86:
14)
        at C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:61:7
        at ControlFlow.emit (C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\ev
ents.js:62:21)
        at ControlFlow.shutdown_ (C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\l
ib\promise.js:2565:10)

        at shutdownTask_.MicroTask (C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver
\lib\promise.js:2490:53)
        at MicroTask.asyncRun (C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\
promise.js:2619:9)
    From asynchronous test:
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (F:\Selenium2\Protractor\TypeScriptProject\ConvertedJSFiles\specs\First.spec.js:20:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Selenium2\Protractor\TypeScriptProject\ConvertedJSFiles\specs\First.spec.js:9:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
Pending:

1) Test login functionality should login the user and allow to logout
  Temporarily disabled with xit

2 specs, 1 failure, 1 pending spec
Finished in 4.931 seconds
[22:52:57] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[22:52:57] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[22:52:57] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[22:52:57] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Comment: is the first `it` block(which contains the element locators directly referenced) which is marked `xit` in this case .. is it working fine?

Comment: @AdityaReddy.. Yes it was working just fine. Issue has come up only when I have used the page object model. There was scope issue which I have resolved now by using fat arrow in calculator.ts file . Now I am facing different issue which I have updated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- You should wrap your beforeEach method at the top of your sample spec.
- I would suggest capitalizing your class. So instead of `export class calculator`, maybe export `Calculator`. This suggestion is more for style guide adherence. I like the [angular.io style guide](https://angular.io/styleguide#!#02-03) (biased opinion)
- After importing a class, you need to call the constructor.
- In your configuration file, you have the `baseUrl` set to google.com. This is weird. Please read the [docs on baseUrl](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L352)
- For a very similar example to typescript / jasmine / protractor, see the [cookbook](https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook/tree/master/protractor-typescript).

So back to your code:

calculator.ts

```
import { element, browser, by, ExpectedConditions as EC, ElementFinder, ElementArrayFinder } from 'protractor';

// style nit
export class Calculator {
  constructor() { /* initialize calculator variables */ }
```

SampleSpec.ts

```
import { browser, by, until, ExpectedConditions as EC, Key, element, ElementFinder } from "protractor";

// don't know what util is doing, but leaving it alone.
import { helperUtility as util } from '../utility/helperUtility';

import { Calculator } from '../pages/calculator';

// remove beforeEach, this should happen in the describe block

describe('Test login functionality', () => {

  // create a local calculator object to be used by tests within
  // this describe block
  let calculator: Calculator;

  beforeEach(() => {
    calculator = new Calculator();  // initialize the calculator
    util.prototype.isAngular(false);
    browser.get('https://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
  });

  it('test mathemetical operation', () => {
     // remove browser.waitForAngular();
     // wait for angular is not needed. Please read the api docs (link below).
     calculator.getResult'1','2','+');
  });
```

Read the [browser.waitForAngular API docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngular) (noted above in the `it` block)

Comment: Congrats on reaching the 1k, well deserved!

Comment: @cnishina Perfect solution to the issues I was facing. I have started using protractor with typescript after visiting your site "https://medium.com/@cnishina/protractor-with-typescript-2eae05016929#.s0w6hy71s". Thanks a lot for both.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe! 1k since September! @HarshEc glad you found the medium article. Its a little dated since we started Protractor TypeScript.